# Sticky forms in php zodiac calculator

Tags: php, html, forms, sticky

I have a program that when you submit your name and birth day, month, and year it calculates your zodiac sign. I want it so that if you don't submit one piece of info and see the error messages, when you click back your answers are still there (sticky). I've taken a look at some other threads but am having trouble implementing it in my specific situation. Thanks!

Here is my html form:

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <html> 
                <head>

                    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

                    <title>
                    Zodiac
                    </title>

                    <style>
                    body{
                        background-image: url('space.jpg');
                        background-color: Blue;
                        background-size: 100%;
                        font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
                        font-size: 150%;
                    }

                    form{
                        background-color: LightBlue;
                        border: solid black 3px;
                        width: 35%;
                    }
                    </style>

                </head>
            <body>

            <center>
                <br>
                <br>
                    <form action="zodiacformHandler.php" method="post">

                    <br>
                    <h1>What's your sign?</h1>
                    <br>
                    Full Name: <input type="text" name="fullName"><br>
                    <br>

                    Month: 
                        <!-- Month dropdown -->
                    <select name="month" size="1">
                        <option disabled selected>  </option>
                        <option value="01">January</option>
                        <option value="02">February</option>
                        <option value="03">March</option>
                        <option value="04">April</option>
                        <option value="05">May</option>
                        <option value="06">June</option>
                        <option value="07">July</option>
                        <option value="08">August</option>
                        <option value="09">September</option>
                        <option value="10">October</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">December</option>
                    </select>

                    Day:
                    <!-- Day dropdown -->
                    <select name="day" size="1">
                        <option disabled selected>  </option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="06">06</option>
                        <option value="07">07</option>
                        <option value="08">08</option>
                        <option value="09">09</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>

                    Year:
                    <!-- Year dropdown -->
                    <select name="year"  size="1">
                        <option disabled selected>  </option>
                        <option value="2014">2014</option>
                        <option value="2013">2013</option>
                        <option value="2012">2012</option>
                        <option value="2011">2011</option>
                        <option value="2010">2010</option>
                        <option value="2009">2009</option>
                        <option value="2008">2008</option>
                        <option value="2007">2007</option>
                        <option value="2006">2006</option>
                        <option value="2005">2005</option>
                        <option value="2004">2004</option>
                        <option value="2003">2003</option>
                        <option value="2002">2002</option>
                        <option value="2001">2001</option>
                        <option value="2000">2000</option>
                        <option value="1999">1999</option>
                        <option value="1998">1998</option>
                        <option value="1997">1997</option>
                        <option value="1996">1996</option>
                        <option value="1995">1995</option>
                        <option value="1994">1994</option>
                        <option value="1993">1993</option>
                        <option value="1992">1992</option>
                        <option value="1991">1991</option>
                        <option value="1990">1990</option>
                        <option value="1989">1989</option>
                        <option value="1988">1988</option>
                        <option value="1987">1987</option>
                        <option value="1986">1986</option>
                        <option value="1985">1985</option>
                        <option value="1984">1984</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="submit">

                    <br><br>
                </form>

            </center>

            </body>
            </html>
```

And here is my php formHandler:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Zodiac Form Handler </title>
                    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                    <style>



                        body{
                            background-image: url('space.jpg');
                            background-color: LightBlue;
                            background-size: 100%;
                            font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
                            font-size: 150%;
                        }

                        #forminfo{
                            padding: 25px;
                        }

                        img.signs{
                            height: 50%;
                        }


                    </style>
                </head>




                <body>

                    <table id="forminfo" align="center" BGCOLOR="#c6e9ee" style="border:3px solid black">
                        <tr><td>
                            <br>
                            <center>
                            <img class="signs" src="signs.png"  align="center"  /></a>
                            <h1>Your Astrological Sign:</h1>
                            </center>
                            <br>
                            <center>
                            <?php
                            $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
                            $month = $_POST['month'];
                            $day = $_POST['day'];
                            $year = $_POST['year'];


                                $formComplete = True; //boolean variable for if the form is valid or invalid

                                //checks to see if name is filled out. 
                                if(empty($_POST['fullName'])){
                                    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR: You didn't enter your name. Please go back and try again.</p>";
                                    $formComplete = False;
                                }

                                //checks to see if the month is filled out.
                                if(empty($_POST['month'])){
                                    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR: You didn't enter a month.  Please go back and try again.</p>";
                                    $formComplete = False;
                                }

                                //checks to see if dislikes is filled out. 
                                if(empty($_POST['day'])){
                                    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR: You didn't enter a day. Please go back and try again.</p>";
                                    $formComplete = False;
                                }

                                //checks to see if a year is entered. 
                                if(empty($_POST['year'])){
                                    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR: You didn't enter a year. Please go back and try again.</p>";
                                    $formComplete = False;
                                }

                            if ($formComplete){

                            function zodiac ( $month, $day, $year) 
                            { 
                               $zodiac = ""; 

                               if     ( ( $month == 3 && $day > 20 ) || ( $month == 4 && $day < 20 ) ) { $zodiac = "Aries"; } 
                               elseif ( ( $month == 4 && $day > 19 ) || ( $month == 5 && $day < 21 ) ) { $zodiac = "Taurus"; } 
                               elseif ( ( $month == 5 && $day > 20 ) || ( $month == 6 && $day < 21 ) ) { $zodiac = "Gemini"; } 
                               elseif ( ( $month == 6 && $day > 20 ) || ( $month == 7 && $day < 23 ) ) { $zodiac = "Cancer"; } 
                               elseif ( ( $month == 7 && $day > 22 ) || ( $month == 8 && $day < 23 ) ) { $zodiac = "Leo"; } 
                               elseif ( ( $month == 8 && $day > 22 ) || ( $month == 9 && $day < 23 ) ) { $zodiac = "Virgo"; } 
                               elseif ( ( $month == 9 && $day > 22 ) || ( $month == 10 && $day < 23 ) ) { $zodiac = "Libra"; } 
                               elseif ( ( $month == 10 && $day > 22 ) || ( $month == 11 && $day < 22 ) ) { $zodiac = "Scorpio"; } 
                               elseif ( ( $month == 11 && $day > 21 ) || ( $month == 12 && $day < 22 ) ) { $zodiac = "Sagittarius"; } 
                               elseif ( ( $month == 12 && $day > 21 ) || ( $month == 1 && $day < 20 ) ) { $zodiac = "Capricorn"; } 
                               elseif ( ( $month == 1 && $day > 19 ) || ( $month == 2 && $day < 19 ) ) { $zodiac = "Aquarius"; } 
                               elseif ( ( $month == 2 && $day > 18 ) || ( $month == 3 && $day < 21 ) ) { $zodiac = "Pisces"; } 

                               return $zodiac; 
                            } 
                            echo ("Hello $fullName! Your zodiac sign is: ");
                            echo zodiac ( $month, $day, $year);

                            }

                            ?>

                            <br><br>

                            <a href="zodiac.html" >Choose another date?</a>
                            <center>
                            <br>
                        </td></tr>
                    </table>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: What kind of trouble do you have? You need to be more specific to get useful answers.

Comment: @StephaneM I wasn't entirely sure the trouble I was having that was the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you've seen the method which uses this method:

```
<input name="someField" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['someField']; ?>" />
```

And are struggling due to the fact that SELECT fields don't work quite the same way, as you have to select the correct value using:

```
<option selected="selected">someValue</option>
```

The best thing to do is probably to "build" your entire select field in PHP

For example

```
// Validate input
if($_POST['month'] != 3) //(Or some other validation check)
{
    //Set the default month as January
    $defaultMonth = 01;
}
else
{
    // Input is valid, leave it as whatever the user set last time
    $defaultMonth = $_POST['month']; //Don't do this without cleaning your input
}

// Define the different options to use in the select field
$months = array(
    01 => 'January',
    02 => 'February',
    03 => 'March',
    04 => 'April',
    ......
    12 => 'December'
);

// "Create" the select field from the array above
echo '<select name="month" size="1">';
foreach($months as $monthNo => $desc)
{
    // Decide if we want to put the selected="selected" line in
    if($monthNo == $defaultMonth)
    {
        $selectedText = "selected='selected' ";
    }
    else
    {
        $selectedText = "";
    }

    echo "<option value='$monthNo' $selectedText>$desc</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

This allows you to build up the form and enter the selected='selected' section at the right point. Your validation can be whatever you need it to be.